# filtering product collection does not work with command

Tags: attributes, collection, magento-2.1, filter, product-collection

I face a problem with a collection. I have fresh products that need to be taken out from store 3 days before the expiration date. I created a command that is called by a cron. I've constructed it like that :

```
public function __construct(
CategoryCollection $categoryCollection, CategoryCollection $productCollection, Category $category, HelperData $helper, Utf8force $utf8helper, State $appState, ObjectManagerFactory $objectManagerFactory, \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource, $name = null
) {
    $this->_categoryCollection = $categoryCollection;
    $this->_productCollection = $productCollection;
    $this->_categoryModel = $category;
    $this->_moduleHelper = $helper;
    $this->_utf8helper = $utf8helper;
    $this->_state = $appState;
    $this->_resource = $resource;
    $params = $_SERVER;
    $params[StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'admin';
    $params[StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'store';
    $this->objectManager = $objectManagerFactory->create($params);
    parent::__construct($name);
}
```

This class contains other function that are working but are not relevant for this question (import new products and categories).

The function is called in the `execute`. We did not set if we will deactivate or delete the product so yet it is called deactivate even if I call delete function.

```
private function _deactivateOldProducts() {
    $today = new \DateTime();
    $dlc = new \DateTime();
    $dlc->add(new \DateInterval('P3D'));
    $this->_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('date_limite',
            array(
                'from' => $today->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'to' => $dlc->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'date' => true
            )
        );
    foreach ($this->_productCollection as $product) {
        $product->delete();
    }
    die();
}
```

I tried both things and they do not work. Whatever attribute I try, I get the exception : `Invalid attribute name: *****`

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is probably caused by the fact that you're using `CategoryCollection` in your constructor to declare your product collection.

You need to replace:

```
public function __construct(
CategoryCollection $categoryCollection, CategoryCollection $productCollection, Category $category, HelperData $helper, Utf8force $utf8helper, State $appState, ObjectManagerFactory $objectManagerFactory, \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource, $name = null
)
```

With:

```
public function __construct(
CategoryCollection $categoryCollection, ProductCollection $productCollection, Category $category, HelperData $helper, Utf8force $utf8helper, State $appState, ObjectManagerFactory $objectManagerFactory, \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource, $name = null
)
```

**Explanations about the error you were getting**

Well it's because **the `id` attribute simply does not exist.**

The following code is what gives you the error:

```
$this->_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('id',
        array(
            'eq' => "1"
        )
    );
```

Theorically, that would basically gives you a collection of one product with the id = 1.

If that's what you wanted to do, you need to replace `id` with `entity_id`:

```
$this->_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id',
        array(
            'eq' => "1"
        )
    );
```

Comment: whatever attribute I try I get the error.

Comment: @ChristopheFerreboeuf see my edited answer ;)

Comment: I understood it when checking entity id. A bad copy-paste, I'll aware you the bounty tomorrow. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `id` attribute. Try `entity_id` instead.

Comment: whatever attribute I try it does the same.